# "Continue" a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of random words with 3 syllables. I used 3 `for` loops, one for each syllable. But I want the program to start creating syllables from a specific position.

In this example, I used the 3 as the position of the first syllable, 4 in the second, and 8 in the third.

I expected the program to print the words `oubo`, `oubu`, `ouca`, `ouce`, ... but that is not what happens. It only print a number and not a position of the string, which causes an error. How can I solve this?

```
letrasRandom = ('a','e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'ba','be','bi','bo','bu','ca','ce','ci','co','cu','da','de','di','do','du','fa','fe','fi','fo','fu','ga','ge','gi','go','gu','ha','he','hi','ho','ia','ie','io','iu','hu','ja','je','ji','jo','ju','ka','ke','ki','ko','ku','la','le','li','lo','lu','ma','me','mi','mo','mu','na','ne','ni','no','nu','pa','pe','pi','po','pu','qu','ra','re','ri','ro','ru','sa','se','si','so','su','ta','te','ti','to','tu','va','ve','vi','vo','vu','wa','we','wi','wo','wu','xa','xe','xi','xo','xu','za','ze','zi','zo','zu', 'cha','cou','che','chi','cho','chu','lha', 'lhe', 'lhi','lho', 'lhu', 'nha','nhe','nhi','nho','nhu','rra','rre','rri','rro','rru','ssa','sse','ssi','sso','ssu','qua','que','qui','quo') 
while True:
    for x in letrasRandom:
        x = 3
        for y in letrasRandom:
            y = 4
            for z in letrasRandom:
                z = 8
                palavra = (x+y+z)
                print(palavra)
```

any hint or solution will be welcome.

Comment: Why are you immediately overwriting the loop variable as the first line of all your loops?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for something like `for x in letrasRandom[3:]`? Or `for i, x in enumerate(letrasRandom):` `if i<3: continue`?

Comment: Please be more specific about what output you want. For example, after reaching `'o'+'u'+'quo'`, should the next string be `'o'+'ba'+'a'`, `'o'+'ba'+'bo'`, or something else?

Comment: Do you want something like `itertools.product(letrasRandom[:3], letrasRandom[3:8], letrasRandom[8:])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you basically want each of the loops to start from different position. In that case, use slicing (`letrasRandom[3:]`) to achieve this:

```
In [23]: letrasRandom =('a','e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'ba','be','bi','bo','bu','ca','ce','ci','co','cu','da','de','di','do','du','fa','fe','fi','fo','
    ...: fu','ga','ge','gi','go','gu','ha','he','hi','ho','ia','ie','io','iu','hu','ja','je','ji','jo','ju','ka','ke','ki','ko','ku','la','le','
    ...: li','lo','lu','ma','me','mi','mo','mu','na','ne','ni','no','nu','pa','pe','pi','po','pu','qu','ra','re','ri','ro','ru','sa','se','si','
    ...: so','su','ta','te','ti','to','tu','va','ve','vi','vo','vu','wa','we','wi','wo','wu','xa','xe','xi','xo','xu','za','ze','zi','zo','zu', 
    ...: 'cha','cou','che','chi','cho','chu','lha', 'lhe', 'lhi','lho', 'lhu', 'nha','nhe','nhi','nho','nhu','rra','rre','rri','rro','rru','ssa'
    ...: ,'sse','ssi','sso','ssu','qua','que','qui','quo') 
    ...: while True:
    ...:     for x in letrasRandom[3:]:
    ...:         for y in letrasRandom[4:]:
    ...:             for z in letrasRandom[8:]:
    ...:                 palavra = (x+y+z)
    ...:                 print(palavra)
```

Which gives the output:

```
oubo
oubu
ouca
ouce
ouci
ouco
oucu
ouda
oude
.
.
.
```

Comment: @ThiagoViana: Yes you can.. If this was a function like `def generate_syllables(letrasRandom, x, y, z):`, you could have used slicing like `letrasRandom[x:]`, `letrasRandom[y:]`, `letrasRandom[z:]` assuming that x, y, z are all valid integers within the length of letrasRandom.